# How to update model from database dll in entity?

Tags: entity-framework, dll, entity-framework-6, entity, dll-injection

Database schema dll I kept it inside.But I've added a primary key in two tables in the database.So I want to update dll.And the updated dll i want to get the current version of my project.How to update dll and add new version to project.

**How to update model dll and insert use project.**

Comment: It's not very clear what your question is. We don't really know what you are doing to "update" a DLL. Unless this is about some specific code it might not be on-topic for SO.

Comment: Hi.I added my model dll.After model is update 2 tables.How to update model dll and add a new dll in project.

Comment: Do you mean "DLL" as in dynamic Link library? If so, then it is unclear what you mean by update. You should [edit] the question and clarify what you mean by DLL, schema, "update" etc. You should probably show your [mcve].

Comment: Thank you.I will follow your suggestions